# Upload an image with MyDac(?) (delphi)

Tags: mysql, delphi

I want create a option to upload an image in delphi (X10, android) to my database with the MyDac but I'm not finding nothing about this, someone can help me with some idea?

Oh ! If someone have a idea most simple about how to send image without need MyDac i was thankful

(What i want do is the a simple system to send attachment (JPG and PNG) from my device for my column in Mysql)

Comment: Are you trying to save images inside your database or what?

Comment: Yes, in the mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your image field as a blob field.  Depending on the size of your pictures you want to store, choose `TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, or LONGBLOB` ((https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html). I found this example on the forum of Devart:

To load graphic files like JPEG in a Blob field, you can use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlobStream: tStream;
  Surf: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  if Image1 <> nil then
  begin
    Surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
    Surf.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    BlobStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    if not TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(BlobStream, Surf, '.jpg') then
      raise EBitmapSavingFailed.Create('No');
    BlobStream.Position := 0;
    myquery2.ParamByName('imagem').LoadFromStream(BlobStream, ftBlob);
    myquery2.ExecSQL;
    Surf.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To load data from the Blob field to the TImage component, use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlobStream: TStream;
begin
  BlobStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  myquery1.GetBlob(myQuery1.FieldByName('imagem')).SaveToStream(BlobStream);
  Blobstream.Position := 0;
  Image2.bitmap.loadfromstream(blobstream);
  BlobStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay to reply.
I'm newbie in delphi, in the first code, you did use " image1 <> nil ", but, how i get the image?  Using ActionList "take photo from library" or using "TimageControl" ?
How to delphi will understand "image1"  as image ?

Comment: Image1 is a TImage (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage) component you put on your form, just like you put a button on it.